# Visual Studio code to Compile and Run using task.json

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

**To Compile & Run in cmd**

g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall fileName.cpp -o fileName&& "./fileName"

For VS code Terminal>Configure Task

In  **task.json**

````
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-Wall",
                "-o",
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "&&",
                "{file}"
  ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}```


Thanks in Advance
````

Comment: actually it working it don't need any quotation                                                                                                      "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-Wall",
                "-o",
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "&&",
                "${file}"
  ],

Comment: edit the question with the update